# MySql Stored Proc - Select query returns null if using where clause not included in select list?

Tags: mysql

I have a proc that simply contains the following:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM table WHERE Id = 1;
```

This always returns null values. If I change the statement to:

```
SELECT Id, Col1, Cold2 FROM table WHERE Id = 1;
```

The row gets returned as expected. Does mySql procs demand that the where clause columns appear in the select list? It doesn't have this behaviour when running the SQL directly in phpMyAdmin.

Here's the code in question:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_player_login
(
IN
    userGraphId INT(11),
    authToken TEXT
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE playerId INT;
    DECLARE newPlayer BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

    SELECT Id INTO playerId FROM player WHERE FacebookGraphId = userGraphId;

    If playerId IS NULL THEN

        -- Create the player.
        SET newPlayer = TRUE;

        -- Get new player defaults.
        SELECT NewPlayerTurns, NewPlayerMoney, NewPlayerMorale, NewPlayerMissilePower FROM defaults WHERE Id = 1;

    END IF;

END #
```

The second SELECT NewPlayerTurns... is the one that returns null values if I don't specify the Id column in the select clause. If I remove the first SELECT Id INTO ...the second query works without the Id in the select clause...? *confused*

Comment: Do you happen to have a parameter that is named `id`?

Comment: Nope. But directly before this statement, there is a "SELECT Id INTO myId FROM otherTable;".

Comment: Yep, it's the previous select, how is that so? All I've done is a SELECT Id INTO Var and it's conflicting?

Comment: Without showing the actual code, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Added the code to the OP.

Comment: @MeshMan . . . Can you edit the question and describe how you know the second query is returning NULL values?  Perhaps it is the method of measuring them that is the problem.

Comment: Well that will teach me to mix column names with local variables names! 5 hours on this silly issue, in between breaks/food. Ah well, my first ever MySQL proc, so going to start prefixing parameters with 'p' and local variables with 'v', so I don't get column name clashes in the future. Thanks to what you said Gorden, I changed the way I was measuring the NULLs and spotted the variables being incorrect. Thanks buddy :).